# Настройка notepad++ и компилятора java

Tags: java, ide, notepad++

Как настроить компилятор java и notepad++? Например, как скомпилировать HelloWorld.java

```
class HelloWorld {    
public static void main (String args []) {    
    System. out. println ("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Для компиляции жмете <kbd>F5</kbd> и пишете `javac $(FILE_NAME)`

Для запуска: `java $(NAME_PART)`